# Save single Json file data to 2 different table in same SQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, json, list, dictionary

I need to save json file data onto mysql db. Currently mysql db mydb with table1 and table2. Need to save some part of data json file to table1 and some to table2. Each table1 and table2 have been created.

Below is sample of json data file

```
{
  "response": {
    "dev_log": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "timestamp": "2020-01-16 10:11:12",
          "email": "johnd@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "timestamp": "2020-02-27 15:33:34",
          "email": "zack@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "timestamp": "2020-02-27 15:34:07",
          "email": "edy@yahoo.com"
        }
      ],
      "total_dev_log": "1423"
    },
    "client_log": {
      "data": [
        {
          "customer_city": "LONDON",
          "customer_login": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
          "customer_state": "MC",
          "details": "aaaaaaaaaaa-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb-cccccccccccccc ",
          "log_number": "1",
          "dept": "Sales",
          "staff_id": "S123",
          "staff_name": "EricY",
          "timestamp": "2020-02-27 15:57:24"
        },
        {
          "customer_city": "SINGAPORE",
          "customer_login": "BBBBBBBBBBBBB",
          "customer_state": "XX",
          "details": "ddddddddd-eeeeeeeeeeee-ffffffffffff ",
          "log_number": "1",
          "dept": "Eng",
          "staff_id": "S456",
          "staff_name": "YongG",
          "timestamp": "2020-02-27 15:57:24"
        }
      ],
      "total_hero_query": "13"
    },
    "response_time": "0.723494",
    "transaction_id": "909122",
    "transaction_status": "OK",
    "transaction_time": "Fri Feb 28 15:27:51 2020"
  }
}
```

Here... in json we have 'dev_log' and 'client_log'.
Thus..all the values of dev_log should be save onto table1 and client_log onto table2 of mydb databse.

The drafted code below

```
import pymysql
import os
import json
#import ast

#Read Json string file
with open('datfile.json', 'r') as f:
   datDict = json.load(f)

#connect to MySQL
con = pymysql.connect(host = 'localhost',user = 'root',passwd = 'root',db = 'mydb')
cursor = con.cursor()

#Parse data to SQL insert
#for i, item in enumerate(datDict):
    #id = ("id", None)
    #timestamp = ("timestamp", None)
    #email = ("email", None)

    #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (id,   timestamp,   email) VALUES (%s,    %s,     %s)", (id,  timestamp,   email))
cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(id, timestamp, email)""", datDict['response']['dev_log']['data'])
con.commit()
con.close()
```

I'm not sure how to save file to sql and some more to 2 different tables. As for now.. i can run the code without any error but return null value as below;

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM table1;
+------+-----------+-------+
| id   | timestamp | email |
+------+-----------+-------+
| NULL | NULL      | NULL  |
| NULL | NULL      | NULL  |
| NULL | NULL      | NULL  |
+------+-----------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

mydb database and table table1 have been created.

I really appreciate your help and advise how I can execute further.

Thank you to all

Comment: what do you do to save your data into sql? [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Json is only a text representation, so you should first load it into Python objects (dicts and lists). On this is done, `data['response']['dev_log']['data']` is a nice list of dicts, as is `data['response']['client_log']['data']`.

So you should be able to use queries close to:

```
data = json.load(jsonfile)
...
curs = con.cursor()    # con is a connection to your database...
curs.executemany("""INSERT INTO dev VALUES(:id, :timestamp, :email)""",
    data['response']['dev_log']['data'])
```

Comment: Hi Sir, I try converting json string to python dictionary and it return error 'ValueError: Expecting property name: line 22 column 5 (char 466)' .... this is my code convert to dict --> with open('datfile.json', 'r') as f:
   datDict = json.load(f)
   print(datDict)

Comment: due to comma...the json is ok.. now...to get the data to sql table

Comment: Serge, I have 'datDict'... and get error ===>  pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':id, :timestamp, :email)' at line 1")

Comment: @chenoi: I only tested it with SQLite3 and I do not use MySQL. There are different possible syntaxes for parameterized queries. You should indeed check your MySQL server manual to find the exact syntax to pass named parameters to a query.

Comment: I have updated my code above and able to run without error but db return null value. Is it the sql command not correct? result to null value?